# (dis)advantages different write methods used in loop

Tags: linux, algorithm, filesystems, fwrite

I'm writing a program in C (although this question holds for other languages) that will run in a loop and write output to a file every time. I can see 5 different methods of doing this.

I wonder what the (dis)advantages for every method are and am especially interested in Linux as OS and btrfs as filesystem (but don't be afraid to answer for other filesystem/OS combinations).

- `createstring()` is a function that will create the current data to be written. For simplicity I'm assuming that only takes nanoseconds
- `SLEEPDURATION_IN_MS` and `EVERY_X_BYTES` are constants that you can choose in order to change advantages/disadvantages, `FILENAME` is just a string containing the path to the file

I'm interested in things like disk activity (i.d. reduction of disk lifetime), safety when code crashes, speed, optimal setting for `EVERY_X_BYTES` depending on `SLEEPDURATION_IN_MS`, ...

If you can think of other methods that would also be nice...

```
    //method 1: open, append and close constantly
    while(1) {
            char *some_string = createstring();
            FILE* some_file = fopen(FILENAME, "a");
            fprintf(some_file, "%s", some_string);
            free(some_string);
            fclose(some_file);
            usleep(SLEEPDURATION_IN_MS);
    }

    //method 2: open once, append constantly, let the system decide to sync
    FILE* some_file = fopen(FILENAME, "a");
    while(1) {
            char *some_string = createstring();
            fprintf(some_file, "%s", some_string);
            free(some_string);
            usleep(SLEEPDURATION_IN_MS);
    }

    //method 3: open once, append and sync everytime
    FILE* some_file = fopen(FILENAME, "a");
    while(1) {
            char *some_string = createstring();
            fprintf(some_file, "%s", some_string);
            free(some_string);
            fflush(some_file);
            usleep(SLEEPDURATION_IN_MS);
    }

    //method 4: open once, append every time, sync sometimes
    FILE* some_file = fopen(FILENAME, "a");
    int bytecount=0;
    while(1) {
            char *some_string = createstring();
            bytecount += strlen(some_string);
            fprintf(some_file, "%s", some_string);
            free(some_string);
            if(bytecount >= EVERY_X_BYTES) {
                    fflush(some_file);
                    bytecount=0;
            }
            usleep(SLEEPDURATION_IN_MS);
    }

    //method 5: open once, save in memory, append and sync sometimes
    FILE* some_file = fopen(FILENAME, "a");
    char *mem;
    char *oldmem = strdup("");
    while(1) {
            char *some_string = createstring();
            asprintf(&mem, "%s%s", oldmem, some_string);
            free(oldmem); free(some_string);
            if(strlen(mem) >= EVERY_X_BYTES) {
                    fprintf(some_file, "%s", mem);
                    fflush(some_file);
                    free(mem);
                    oldmem = strdup("");
            } else {
                    oldmem = mem;
            }
            usleep(SLEEPDURATION_IN_MS);
    }
```

Comment: Where do your files all get closed?  That needs to be counted, too.

Comment: In method 1 I close the file after appending because it opens again every time before appending. All other methods don't close the file because they only open it once and keep appending until the program crashes or is killed in which case the system will close the file. The program is meant to never stop running.